# How to get value of a module.exports description in another file [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot that has a help command which sends an embed with fields, each one corresponding to a command. I want to automatically set the values of these fields to the correct command file description. This is an example of the command file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "Kicks the mentioned user. Administrator permissions required",
    execute(message, args) {
      // command code
}
```

I am trying to set the field values to the module exports description. If this is possible, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Client#commands#get` to get the object of the command, then simply use `.description` to get that command's description.

For this example I will use `Client` as the Client object, however if yours is Bot or anything else, adjust the code accordingly.

Example Module:

```
module.exports = {
   name: 'testCommand',
   description: 'Hello World!'
}
```

How to get the description:

```
const cmd = Client.commands.get('testCommand');

console.log(cmd.description);
// 'Hello World!'
```

If you're inside the command you want to get the description of, simply use `this` to reference the current command

```
module.exports = {
   name: 'testCommand',
   description: 'Hello World!',

   // this.description = 'Hello World!'
}
```